# Why does setting PROMPT have no effect in grml's zshrc?

Tags: zsh, grml

Trying to set the `PROMPT` or `PS1` variables to customise the ZSH shell prompt with the popular [GRML zshrc](https://grml.org/zsh/) config, it has no effect, nothing happens at all:

```
root@machine ~ # PROMPT="> "
root@machine ~ #
```

Why is that and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3):

The GRML ZSH prompt system was revamped in 2013; the author's posts about it:

1. http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2013/001/
2. http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2013/002/
3. http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2013/003/

Post (2) explains the issue:

> You will have to turn off the grml theme (and any other theme for that matter) beforehand. So your customisation becomes this:
>
> ```
> # I want my own prompt!
> prompt off
> # customisation here
> ```

**You can use that method, or you can use the newer `zstyle` based approach described in posts (1) and (3) above.**